# How to create custom ner components in spaCy v3

Tags: nlp, spacy

I m trying to add an entityRuler but i keep getting this error :[E002] Can't find factory for 'ruler' for language French (fr), i don't know how to create a custom component for V3 and i have only found example for the older version and the documentation kinda of confused me.

```js
pattern = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Neoledge"}]
ruler.add_patterns(pattern)
nlp.add_pipe('ruler')
```

Edit:

```py
@Language.component('rulerORG') 
def rulerORG(doc):     
    ORG = ["...",]     
    ruler= EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)     
    for O in ORG:        
        ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "ORG", "pattern": O}])     
        return doc    

nlp.add_pipe('rulerORG')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're trying to create an EntityRuler? If so you should write your code like this:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.blank("en")
pattern = [{"label": "ORG", "pattern": "Neoledge"}]
ruler = nlp.add_pipe('entity_ruler', config={"overwrite_ents":True})
ruler.add_patterns(pattern)
```

The EntityRuler and NER pipelines are different - NER is statistical, the EntityRuler is rule-based.

The way components are added to the pipeline changed between v2 and v3 and it looks like you have a mix of code.

You can see an example of the approach I outlined here in [this part of the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/rule-based-matching#entityruler-usage).

Comment: thanks for helping, i copied your code to try it and sadly i m receiving the same error. However i ended doing this and it's working but since i figured you know more about spaCy i would show you if what i did is correct : `@Language.component('rulerORG')
def rulerORG(doc):
    ORG = ["...",]
    ruler= EntityRuler(nlp, overwrite_ents=True)
    for O in ORG:
        ruler.add_patterns([{"label": "ORG", "pattern": O}])
    return doc    nlp.add_pipe('rulerORG')`

Comment: What spaCy version are you using? Also don't put multiline code in a comment, it's too hard to read. Edit your question to put it at the end.

Comment: There were some issues with my code, I fixed it. I really suggest you use the example in the docs as a starting point though.

Comment: i edited the code, i m using 3.1.1 version

Comment: OK, thanks for the update. I would say go over the official docs again - copy and paste them as a starting point. For examle, in your example code 1. you don't need a decorator 2. You don't need to call `EntityRuler` (see how I use `ruler = nlp.add_pipe(...)`. In v2 you created a pipe and added it to the nlp object, but in v3 you get the object from the pipe and then call functions on it.

Comment: I see, i will go back to the documentation and thank you for helping